# How to index a Json object with object and its reference in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, mapper

I am working with Elasticsearch recently, and I meet a problem that don't know how to solve it.

I have a Json like:

```
{
  "objects": [
    "object1": {
     "id" : "12345",  
     "name":"abc"
    },
    "12345"
   ]
}
```

Object2 is a reference of object1, when I trying to saving(or called indexing) into elastic search, it says:

"org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse"

After I google I found that because object1 is an object, but object 2 is considered as a string. 
We cannot change our json in our project, so in this case how can I save it in the elasticsearch?

Thanks for any help and suggestion.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON - test it at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that. I updated it and thanks for your remaind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you do that?
I run this command and it works.

```
PUT test/t1/1
{
  "objects": {
    "object1": {
     "id" : "12345",  
     "name":"abc"
    },
    "object2": "12345"
   }
}
```

and the result is:

```
{
   "_index": "test",
   "_type": "t1",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "result": "created",
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "created": true
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
Depending on your requirements one of these may solve your problem:

```
PUT test/t1/2
{
   "objects": [
      {
         "object1": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "abc"
         }
      },
      {
         "object2": "12345"
      }
   ]
}

PUT test/t1/2
{
   "objects": [
      {
         "object1": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "abc"
         },
         "object2": "12345"
      },
      {
       ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quike reply, sorry, It should be [] rather than {}, I revised it.

Comment: I've Updated the answer :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! but we got our json from other project which means we cannot change anything about the json string. Do you know any other ways to solve it? perhaps any setting or configuration in elasticsearch?

Comment: Sorry! I don't know any solution for that case.

Comment: Thanks all the same. We desicied change our design to avoid this issue. Thank you.